# Combining nltk.RegexpParser grammars

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, nltk

As my next step towards learning more about NLP, I'm trying to implement a simple heuristic that improves results beyond simple n-grams.

Per the Stanford Collocations PDF linked below they mention that passing "candidate phrases through a part of-speech filter which only lets through those patterns that are likely to be “phrases"" will produce better results than simply using the most frequently occuring bi-grams. 
Source: Collocations, page 143 - 144: https://nlp.stanford.edu/fsnlp/promo/colloc.pdf

The table on page 144 has 7 tag patterns. In order, the NLTK POS tag equivalent is:

JJ NN

NN

JJ JJ NN

JJ NN NN

NN JJ NN

NN NN NN

NN IN NN

In the code below, I can get the desired result when I *independently* apply each grammar below. However when I try to combine the same grammars I don't receive the desired result.

In my code, you can see that I uncomment one sentence, uncomment 1 grammar, run it and check the result.

I should be able to combine all sentences, run it through the combined grammar (just 3 of them in the code below) and get the desired results.

> My question is, how do I correctly combine grammars?

I'm assuming that combining grammars is like an 'OR', find this pattern, OR this pattern...

Thanks in advance.

```
import nltk

# The following sentences are correctly grouped with <JJ>*<NN>+. 
# Should see: 'linear function', 'regression coefficient', 'Gaussian random variable' and 
# 'cumulative distribution function'
SampleSentence = "In mathematics, the term linear function refers to two distinct, although related, notions"
#SampleSentence = "The regression coefficient is the slope of the line of the regression equation."
#SampleSentence = "In probability theory, Gaussian random variable is a very common continuous probability distribution."
#SampleSentence = "In probability theory and statistics, the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of a real-valued random variable X, or just distribution function of X, evaluated at x, is the probability that X will take a value less than or equal to x."

# The following sentences are correctly grouped with <NN.?>*<V.*>*<NN>
# Should see 'mean squared error' and # 'class probability function'. 
#SampleSentence = "In statistics, the mean squared error (MSE) of an estimator measures the average of the squares of the errors, that is, the difference between the estimator and what is estimated."
#SampleSentence = "The class probability function is interesting"

# The sentence below is correctly grouped with <NN.?>*<IN>*<NN.?>*. 
# should see 'degrees of freedom'.
#SampleSentence = "In statistics, the degrees of freedom is the number of values in the final calculation of a statistic that are free to vary."

SampleSentence = SampleSentence.lower()

print("\nFull sentence: ", SampleSentence, "\n")

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(SampleSentence)
textTokens = nltk.Text(tokens)    

# Determine the POS tags.
POStagList = nltk.pos_tag(textTokens)    

# The following grammars work well *independently*
grammar = "NP: {<JJ>*<NN>+}"
#grammar = "NP: {<NN.?>*<V.*>*<NN>}"    
#grammar = "NP: {<NN.?>*<IN>*<NN.?>*}"


# Merge several grammars above into a single one below. 
# Note that all 3 correct grammars above are included below. 

'''
grammar = """
            NP: 
                {<JJ>*<NN>+}
                {<NN.?>*<V.*>*<NN>}
                {<NN.?>*<IN>*<NN.?>*}
        """
'''

cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)

result = cp.parse(POStagList)

for subtree in result.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t.label() == 'NP'):
    print("NP Subtree:", subtree)
```

Comment: If you can help me understand more, you don't want to write 3 separate line like this grammar = """
            NP: 
                {<JJ>*<NN>+}
                {<NN.?>*<V.*>*<NN>}
                {<NN.?>*<IN>*<NN.?>*}
        """.  Instead you want a regex pattern in single line which can accommodate all the 3 patterns.

Comment: Hi Rahul. I want to somehow combine the 3 regex patterns so that they produce the same results that they produced individually. I'm impartial how it's written with 1, 2, 3+ lines. I'll try your code below over the next few days. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, go ahead!! I have tried for multiple scenarios and it holds. Try and get back for any other issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my comment is what you are looking for, then below is the answer:

```
grammar = """
            NP: 
                {<JJ>*<NN.?>*<V.|IN>*<NN.?>*}"""
```